# How to retrieve the exports from TypeScript files with unknown at advance paths in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Below `filePath` is unknown at advance, however expecting the `.ts` file:

```js
const filePath: string | undefined = process.argv[2];

// check for the undefined value ...
// check for the valid typescript file path ...
```

Now, how to read this file, transpile it and get exports (from already transpiled JavaScript module)?
For example file with below content:

```js
export default {
    key1: "VALUE_1",
    key2: "VALUE_2"
}
```

```js
const filePath: string | undefined = process.argv[2];

// check for the indefined value ...
// check for the valid typescript file path ...

// read file with path `filePath`
// transpile file with path `filePath`
const defaultExport = { /* get the default export */ };

console.log(exportedObject.key1); // => "VALUE_1"
console.log(exportedObject.key2); // => "VALUE_2"
```

I had heared about **dynamic loading**, but used it mainly in Browser.js, where dynamic loading means the creating of `<script>` tag. For the Node.js, the dynamic loading concept could not be same. Besides this, the `import()` syntax is available for ES modules only, while in Node.js is Common.js-first.

I assume what I want is possible because Webpack, Gulp and NuxtJS supports confguration written by TypeScript, herewidth the file path is unknown advance.

### Use case

If shortly, I want to generate the dummy data and use in Pug template (not for MVC, just for local static HTML).

**gulp-pug** plugin allows to pass some variables to Pug template:

```js
return src('./src/*.pug')
    .pipe(
      pug({
        locals: {
            exampleVariable1: 1,
            exampleVariable2: "foo"
        }
      })
    )
    .pipe(dest('./dist'));
```

Of course, these variables may be took from ".json" or ".yaml" file.
But I want take them from TypeScript file:

```js
type Example = {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;    
}

const sampleArray: Array<string> = [
  { foo: "ALPHA", bar: 1 },
  { foo: "BAR", bar: 2 },
];

export default sampleArray;
```

Now,

```js
// transpile TypeScript file
// get sampleArray as default import

return src('./src/*.pug')
    .pipe(
      pug({
        locals: {
            sampleArray
        }
      })
    )
    .pipe(dest('./dist'));
```

Why TypeScript is:

1. Type safety
2. Usage of libraries (for example for generating of dummy data)
3. The mock data generating code could be reused in the future

Comment: _TypeScript only performs static type checking at compile time! The generated JavaScript, which is what actually runs when you run your code, does not know anything about the types._, in other words: Typescript is compile time, Javascript is runtime, so there is no way of `retrieve the exports from unknown at advance paths`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Thank you for the comment.The target is compile the TypeScript to JavaScript, then import compiled JavaScript. It must be possible because, for example, Webpack of Gulp supports configuration files with ".ts" extension.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on your use case? Are you trying to make a library that can use a typescript config file like the ones you mention? Things get tremendously more complicated if the file you want to parse `import`s other modules, and/or depends on specific `tsconfig.json` settings.

Comment: @EricHaynes, yes of course. I added the "Use case" section to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is with `ts-node`'s register. First, `npm i ts-node`. Then you can use it like so:

```js
import 'ts-node/register';

export const loadData = () => {
  const filePath: string | undefined = process.argv[2];

  // if you have @typescript-eslint, it will complain about this
  // `require`, so suppress the warning

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
  const data = require(filePath);

  // this allows it to work with commonjs modules as well, but
  // could also just return `data.default`
  return data.default ? data.default : data;
};
```

This should be fine for files like your example, where the content are values that could just as easily have been in JSON. If the files are more complex, you should still be fine if they're in the current project.

If the files are more complex and live **outside** of the current project, there are some caveats:

- The file will be parsed based on the `tsconfig.json` in your current project, so if the file is in some other project that has different settings, it could fail to parse.
- If the file `import`s any npm modules, node will try to resolve them relative the current project
- If you compile this and run the artifact somewhere else (i.e. not in a dev environment), there won't be a `tsconfig.json` at all, so it will use a [default config](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/configuration/#default-config)

If any of those are possible, I think it's probably better to compile them separately and use the compiled `.js` output. It *could* be done with the [TypeScript compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API), but that gets far more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer! With great pleasure I give the reputation prize.